# SQL Server 2008 problem

Tags: sql-server

I have table in following structure...

```
        ReturnID SumbitID Status

          1           1    1 
          1          NULL  2
          2            2   3
          3            3   1
          3            3   1
```

I want this output.....

```
        RetunrID TotalAttempt Success
           1        2           1
           2        1           0
           3        2           2
```

Count Of ReturnID is TotalAttempt, when ReturnID = sumbitID and status =1 Then it count as success...
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
SELECT
    T.ReturnID
,   COUNT(T.ReturnID) AS TotalAttempt
,   SUM(CASE WHEN T.ReturnID = T.sumbitID AND T.Status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Status
FROM dbo.MyTable T
group by T.ReturnID
```

Comment: Working But you have to add group by clause at last....SELECT
    T.ReturnID
,   COUNT(T.ReturnID)  AS TotalAttempt 
,   SUM(CASE WHEN T.ReturnID = T.sumbitID AND T.Statusa = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Status
FROM
    @table T GROUP BY T.ReturnID

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
SELECT T.ReturnID , COUNT(T.ReturnID) AS TotalAttempt , SUM(CASE WHEN T.ReturnID = T.sumbitID AND T.Statusa = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Status FROM @table T GROUP BY T.ReturnID
```